# Validate array keys of a php array

Tags: php, arrays, validation

I have two arrays: `$values` and `$availableKeys`. I want to throw an exception if `$values` contains not allowed keys. At the moment I am running this code.

```
    foreach ($values as $key => $value) {
        if (!in_array($key, $availableKeys)) {
            throw new RuntimeException(
                'Not allowed key'
            );
        }
    }
```

Exists a better way to validate an array? The question [Validate PHP Array Key>Value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26864620/validate-php-array-keyvalue) is not responding to my question.

Comment: *Is not satisfying me.* is not a PHP error. Do you get any when you run the code?

Comment: I've update the question removing that sentence. The point is under the code: "Exists a better way to validate an array?"

Answer (score 2):

```
if (array_diff_key($values, array_flip($availableKeys))) {
    throw new RuntimeException(..);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i can only say that test, that key is present in array, is more faster. So make array $availableKeys not [key1, key2...] but [key1=>1, key2=>1...]. ie, flip your current array

```
foreach ($values as $key => $value) {
        if (!isset($availableKeys[$key])) {
            throw new RuntimeException(
                'Not allowed key'
            );
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use array_diff() to search for unallowed keys:

```
$allowedKeys = array("a","b","c");
$test = array("a" => "asdf", "c" => "asdf", "d" => "asdf");
$notAllowedKeys = array_diff(array_keys($test), $allowedKeys);
if($notAllowedKeys) {
    print "One or more keys are not allowed";
    print_r($notAllowedKeys);  
}
```

Live example: http://3v4l.org/hi2sP

Comment: Don't use `empty` for variables which are guaranteed to exist. `if ($notAllowedKeys)` does exactly the same thing without needlessly suppressing error reporting.

Comment: Why shouldn't empty() be used? array_diff() returns an empty array if no difference is found, so why not check an empty array with empty()?

Comment: Because you're **needlessly suppressing error reporting.** See [The Definitive Guide To PHP's isset And empty](http://kunststube.net/isset/)

Comment: What do you mean? In the example a key "b" is not set in $test and it still works.