# Server responds with an XML that SimpleXMLElement cannot convert to Object

Tags: php, xml

When I make a HTTP GET request, with curl, via php, I get this response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<root>
    <apiStatus>ok</apiStatus>
    <matches>1</matches>
    <unit type="campaign">
        <id>42</id>
        <name>think_deep</name>
    </unit>
    <units>1</units>
</root>
```

When I try to get this output, to create a SimpleXMLElement, I get this erropr:

```
PHP Warning:  SimpleXMLElement::__construct(): Entity: line 1: parser error : Start tag expected, '<' not found in /home/simone/Development/dotadv/cxense/scripts/SearchForCampaign.php on line 35
PHP Warning:  SimpleXMLElement::__construct(): 1 in /home/simone/Development/dotadv/cxense/scripts/SearchForCampaign.php on line 35
PHP Warning:  SimpleXMLElement::__construct(): ^ in /home/simone/Development/dotadv/cxense/scripts/SearchForCampaign.php on line 35
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'String could not be parsed as XML' in /home/simone/Development/dotadv/cxense/scripts/SearchForCampaign.php:35
Stack trace:
#0 /home/simone/Development/dotadv/cxense/scripts/SearchForCampaign.php(35): SimpleXMLElement->__construct('1')
#1 {main} thrown in /home/simone/Development/dotadv/cxense/scripts/SearchForCampaign.php on line 35
```

With a var_dump() I discovered that the output is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<root>
    <apiStatus>ok</apiStatus>
    <matches>1</matches>
    <unit type="campaign">
        <id>42</id>
        <name>think_deep</name>
    </unit>
    <units>1</units>
</root>
bool(true)
bool(true)
```

So, ... What kind of issue is this?

```
$curl = curl_init();
$url = 'http://stage.emediate.eu' . $request->uri();
curl_setopt_array($curl, [
    CURLOPT_URL => $url,
]);

$resp = curl_exec($curl);
var_dump($resp, true);
```

Comment: show your code, because xml is fine - https://eval.in/404775

Comment: when not set CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, curl_exec return true or false.  so, result of var_dump is `bool(true) bool(true)`. :)

Comment: Oh, yess!! This is the answer. Please, add this commend as answer =)

Comment: You are welcome ! :)

Comment: No! I am sensorario!!

Comment: :) By the way. What do you think about http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31604960/validate-array-keys-of-a-php-array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you do not set option `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER`, curl_exec return true or false as result of request. So, $resp gets true, which we can see in the output of `var_dump($resp, true);`

```
bool(true)
bool(true)
```

To receive the xml as result change your code to

```
curl_setopt_array($curl, [
    CURLOPT_URL => $url,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1
]);
```